# How to find revision number of subclasses

Tags: svn, directory, subclass, revision

I have a svn address and it has 2 different sub class like this;

- `/trunk/boo`
- `/trunk/foo`

I checked out `/trunk/boo` to `/home/Documents/boo`

and

`/trunk/foo` to `/home/Documents/foo` folders.

I can find revision number of trunk by using

> $ svn info

command. (For example 1918)

But I want to know revision numbers of boo and foo separately.
 (For example : revision number of foo => 1916   revision number of boo => 1918)

Is there a way to do this?

(Sorry for my english it is not my native language :) )

Comment: Will this work? `svn info /home/Documents/foo` and `svn info /home/Documents/boo`? Otherwise, we're not understanding what you're looking for. Do you mean _subdirectories_ instead of _subclasses_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know revision numbers of boo and foo separately

You already have this information in `svn info` output **now**!!!

For *any node* of Working Copy `svn info` have 3 "Last Changed ..." strings, last in output. You want to see `Last Changed Rev` value

Branch

```
\branches\FullHTML>svn info
Path: .
...
Last Changed Author: lazybadger
Last Changed Rev: 2
Last Changed Date: 2013-11-28 00:13:01 +0600 (Чт, 28 ноя 2013)
```

Trunk

```
\trunk>svn info
Path: .
...
Last Changed Author: lazybadger
Last Changed Rev: 5
Last Changed Date: 2014-02-07 12:06:56 +0600 (Пт, 07 фев 2014)
```

Another way (easier parsing) is `svn ls -v /PATH/TO/COMMON/PARENT` (first column in output)

```
>svn ls -v
      5 lazybadg              фев 07  2014 ./
      2 lazybadg              ноя 28  2013 branches/
      2 lazybadg          146 ноя 28  2013 readme.textile
      1 www-data              ноя 27  2013 tags/
      5 lazybadg              фев 07  2014 trunk/
```

(I have single branch in \branches, thus - revision of `\branches\FullHTML` is revision of `\branches` )

Comment: Thank you man. I find another solution using your suggestion which is better for me. It is easily get the revision number of any class like that;

CURRENT_REVISION=`svn info http:///trunk/foo |grep '^Revision:' | sed -e 's/^Revision: //'`
echo "Current revision is foo :  " $CURRENT_REVISION

CURRENT_REVISION=`svn info http:///trunk/boo |grep '^Revision:' | sed -e 's/^Revision: //'`
echo "Current revision is boo :  " $CURRENT_REVISION

Answer (score 0):

Are `boo` and `foo` folders or `Java` `Class`es? Either way, the `info` command additionally takes a target resource that can be any physical file/folder.

`svn info [TARGET[@REV]...]`

So you could navigate to the trunk and do,

`svn info boo`

`svn info foo`

See the [info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) command description for more options.